# Unique items in list of sets

Tags: python

If I have list of sets:

```
>>> lst = [{1, 2}, {0, 1}, {1, 2}]
```

How to return unique items?

Trying well known `set()` does not work:

```
>>> set(lst)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

Comment: please provide sample output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "unique items" you mean unique sets, you could just use `frozenset`, which is a hashable but immutable version of `set`. You could either build your sets as `frozenset` objects initially, or if you need to mutate them, do something like:

```
uniques = set(frozenset(s) for s in lst)
```

Then:

```
>>> uniques
set([frozenset([1, 2]), frozenset([0, 1])])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [8]: lst = [{1, 2}, {0, 1}, {1, 2}]

In [9]: reduce(set.union, lst)
Out[9]: {0, 1, 2}
```

#### Edit:

A better version of above:

```
In [1]: lst = [{1, 2}, {0, 1}, {1, 2}]

In [2]: set.union(*lst)
Out[2]: {0, 1, 2}
```

Comment: Very nice solution.

Comment: You can also write this as `set().union(*lst)` which means you don't have to worry about Python 2/3 changes as to where `reduce` is...

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> reduce(lambda a, b: a.union(b), lst)
{0, 1, 2}
```

**EDIT**

Given that the OP appears to want unique subsets:

```
>>> set(tuple(sorted(s)) for s in lst)
{(0, 1), (1, 2)}
```

Comment: Personally I used the same line in my code - I went with tuples instead frozen sets. @spruceb answer should be IMHO the correct one for the question title, given TypeError.

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve this by:

```
>>> lst = [{1, 2}, {0, 1}, {1, 2}]
>>> set(frozenset(s) for s in lst)   
set([frozenset([1, 2]), frozenset([0, 1])])
```

Check [Frozen Set](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/types-set.html) document for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_unique_sets(l):
    unique_sets = []
    for s in l:
        if s not in unique_sets:
            unique_sets.append(s)
    return unique_sets

lst = [{1, 2}, {0, 1}, {1, 2}]
print(get_unique_sets(lst))
```

**Output**

```
[{1, 2}, {0, 1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do your input list items have to be sets or could they be tuples instead?

`set()` works on tuples in my test (py 2.7):

```
>>> lst = [(1,2), (0,1), (1,2)]
>>> set(lst)
set([(1, 2), (0, 1)])
```

If your input is always a list of sets, you can just do a transformation to tuples before and a transformation back to sets after:

```
>>> lst = [{1, 2}, {0, 1}, {1, 2}]
>>> lst
[set([1, 2]), set([0, 1]), set([1, 2])]
>>> set(lst)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
>>> lst2 = [tuple(x) for x in lst]
>>> lst2
[(1, 2), (0, 1), (1, 2)]
>>> lst2 = set(lst2)
>>> lst2
set([(1, 2), (0, 1)])
>>> lst2 = list(lst2)
>>> lst2
[(1, 2), (0, 1)]
>>> lst = [set(x) for x in lst2]
>>> lst
[set([1, 2]), set([0, 1])]
```

Not sure if this is the best option, but it works in the example case you gave, hope this helps :)